# Magento : display form in modal box

Tags: javascript, magento

I have a contact form in magento like this :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZlsVu.png

I've downloaded modalbox.js and modalbox.css

I tried this script :

```
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
openContactsForm=function(url,title){
    Modalbox.hide();
    Modalbox.show(url,{title:title,width:650,overlay:true,overlayClose:true});
}
document.observe('dom:loaded',
                 function(){
                     var links=$A(document.getElementsByTagName('a'));
                     links.each(function(link){
                         if(link.href.match(/\/extendedcontacts\/$/)){
                             url=link.href.replace(/\/extendedcontacts\/$/,'/iextendedcontacts');
                             if(document.URL.indexOf("https://")>-1){
                                 url=url.replace('http://','https://');
                             }
                             $(link).writeAttribute('onclick',
                                                    'openContactsForm("'+url+'", "'+$(link).title+'"); return false;');
                             $(link).writeAttribute('href',
                                                    'javascript:openContactsForm("'+url+'", "'+$(link).title+'");');
                         }
                     });
                 });
//]]></script>
```

So this script looks for a link in the footer when clicked on that link, it displays a modal box with the contact form but it didn't work.

Comment: Any error in Fire Bug Console?

Comment: yes errors fires when click the link :
Uncaught Modalbox isn't initialized modalbox.js:106
Modalbox.Methods.hide modalbox.js:106
openContactsForm extendedcontacts:320
onclick extendedcontacts:1
Uncaught Modalbox isn't initialized modalbox.js:106
Modalbox.Methods.hide modalbox.js:106
openContactsForm extendedcontacts:320
(anonymous function)